# Guice - programmatically created bindings

Tags: java, generics, types, guice

I am using Guice for DI. I want to create dynamic binding of a generic class as replacement for the manual bindings I am creating now.

The manual way is working fine so far:

```
        bind(new TypeLiteral<DAOService<SourceSystem, UUID>>() {})
            .to(new TypeLiteral<DAOServiceImpl<SourceSystem, UUID>>() {});
```

But I want to something like this:

```
    final String poPackage = PersistableObject.class.getPackage().getName();
    final Reflections r = new Reflections(poPackage);
    final Class<DAOService> ifClass = DAOService.class;
    final Class<DAOServiceImpl> implClass = DAOServiceImpl.class;

    for (Class<? extends PersistableObject> dbClass : r.getSubTypesOf(PersistableObject.class)) {
        final ParameterizedType ifPt = Types.newParameterizedType(ifClass, dbClass, UUID.class);
        final ParameterizedType implPt = Types.newParameterizedType(implClass, dbClass, UUID.class);

        final TypeLiteral<?> fromLiteral = TypeLiteral.get(ifPt);
        final TypeLiteral<?> toLiteral = TypeLiteral.get(implPt);

        bind(fromLiteral).to(toLiteral); // not compiling!
    }
```

This does not compile because:

```
[50,30] no suitable method found for to(com.google.inject.TypeLiteral<capture#1 of ?>)
```

Is there the possibility to programmatically create bindings in Guice with dynamic created TypeLiterals?

Comment: Why do you want to do it "dynamically"?

Comment: You know that it is safe because of the way you construct the type literals... So a hacky way to do it would be to drop the `<?>` from the type literals, and so do it using raw types.

Comment: @AndyTurner: thanks -  that solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @AndyTurner. drop the `<?>` from `TypeLiteral` solved the issue for m. This is compiling and working:

```
    final Class<UUID> idClass = UUID.class;
    final Class<DAOService> ifClass = DAOService.class;
    final Class<DAOServiceImpl> implClass = DAOServiceImpl.class;

    for (Class<? extends PersistableObject> dbClass : r.getSubTypesOf(PersistableObject.class)) {
        final ParameterizedType ifPt = Types.newParameterizedType(ifClass, dbClass, idClass);
        final ParameterizedType implPt = Types.newParameterizedType(implClass, dbClass, idClass);
        final TypeLiteral fromLiteral = TypeLiteral.get(ifPt);
        final TypeLiteral toLiteral = TypeLiteral.get(implPt);

        bind(fromLiteral).to(toLiteral);
    }
```